# Creating a dynamic list of screen in DrawerNavigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm sure this is related to some of the react complications that I haven't fully grasped yet, but I'm trying to create a dynamic list of navs in my drawer but it seems the `stash` object which I'm trying to use to build the nav is undefined at render (just a guess based on what I've seen). How is something like this done?

```
function RootNavigator() {
  let initialRouteName: keyof RootStackParamList = 'Root';

  return (
    <RootStack.Navigator initialRouteName={initialRouteName}>
      <RootStack.Screen name="Root"  component={DrawerNavigator} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    </RootStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const DrawerNav = createDrawerNavigator<RootTabParamList>();

function DrawerNavigator () {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const userInfo = React.useContext(UserContext);

  let stashPages: JSX.Element[] = [];

  // userInfo.stashes is defined and is an array
  if (userInfo?.stashes) {
    // just for simplicity
    const stash = userInfo.stashes[0];
    
    stashPages.push(<DrawerNav.Screen
      key={stash.SK}
      name="Stash"
      component={StashScreen}
      options={({ navigation }: RootTabScreenProps<'Stash'>) => ({
        label: stash.name,
        drawerLabel: stash.name // this specifically is what is causing me trouble
      })
    } />);
  }
  
  return (
    <DrawerNav.Navigator initialRouteName="TabOne">
      {stashPages}
    </DrawerNav.Navigator>
  )
}
```

What I see in the UI is the nav simply named "Stash" which I presume is because of this line from the docs regarding the `drawerLabel` property: `When undefined, the title is used.` Additionally, if I use a raw string there, the ui reflects it accordingly. What do I need to understand here to make this work?